# JAX-RS filter not getting called

Tags: web-services, rest, jax-rs, weblogic, weblogic12c

I have a filter defined in a file CheckSessionFilter.java, like this:

```
@Provider
@SessionChecker
public class CheckSessionFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws WebApplicationException {
        ....
    }
```

In another file, SessionChecker.java, I have:

```
@Target({ ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD })
@Retention(value = RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@NameBinding
public @interface SessionChecker {}
```

My web service is defined in Services.java as:

```
@Path("Services")
public class Services {

    @POST
    @SessionChecker
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("LogIn")
    public Response logIn(@Context HttpServletRequest request, Parameters requestParameters) {
        ....
    }
}
```

I deployed my web service on WebLogic 12.2.1. The web service works fine. But the filter is not getting called at all. What could be wrong?

Do I need to put anything in web.xml?

Thanks in advance.

Edited to include web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
  <display-name>XXXXXXXX</display-name> 
  <servlet>
       <servlet-name>JAX-RS Application</servlet-name>
       <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
       <init-param>
           <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
           <param-value>rest.application.config.ApplicationConfig</param-value>
       </init-param>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>JAX-RS Application</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping> 
</web-app>
```

Updated web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
    <display-name>XXXXXXXX</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>JAX-RS Application</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
            <param-value>rest.application.config.ApplicationConfig</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>JAX-RS Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Edited to add application config:

```
package rest.application.config;

import java.util.Set;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;
import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;

@ApplicationPath("resources")
public class ApplicationConfig extends Application {

    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        return getRestClasses();
    }

    //Auto-generated from RESTful web service wizard
    private Set<Class<?>> getRestClasses() {
        Set<Class<?>> resources = new java.util.HashSet<Class<?>>();
        resources.add(Services.class);
        return resources;    
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you defined front controller & url pattern in your web.xml??

Comment: I edited my post above to include web.xml. As mentioned in my original post, my web service is working fine. It is just that the filter is not getting called. What front controller are you talking about? I have seen all the examples on filters and non of them mentioned about front controller.

Comment: Looks like you are using Jersey 1.x (com.sun..ServletContainer), but the `ContainerRequestFilter` is a Jersey(Jax-RS)-2.x filter. Jersey 1.x has the same filter, but it is under a different packaged, with a little different interface contract

Comment: How do I change to Jersey 2.x container then? I am using Weblogic 12.2.1 and have deployed jax-rs(2.0,2.21.1.0).

Comment: You should be using [this ServletContainer](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/deployment.html#deployment.servlet.2)

Comment: Hi peeskillet, I modified web.xml to change the servlet container to the one you suggested. I edited my original post to put the updated web.xml there. But the filter is still not getting called.

Comment: Please post your `ApplicationConfig` class

Comment: You need to register the filter also, in your application class.

Comment: Hi peeskillet, I posted ApplicationConfig in my original post. How do I register the filter? I checked a few examples on the web, and they all don't need registration (may be they are for Jersey 1.x?).

Comment: When you use scanning, it picks up `@Path` and `@Provider` classes and automatically registers them. Those are probably the examples you are seeing. You are not using scanning. You are explicitly registering your resources, in `getClasses()`, so you also need to register the filter. If you want to use scanning.  Read through the very first link I provided. It shows different ways to configure your Jersey2 application

Comment: I modified getClasses() to add in my filter classes, and this time the filter is getting called. Thanks a lot! By the way, you mean to say that if I specify <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name> in web.xml, I can specify the packages of the web service class and filter class, and I won't need an ApplicationConfig any more?

Comment: Yup.... also you can post the changes you made in an answer. I am too lazy :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to peeskillet, I have found the solution, which is to add the filter in the ApplicationConfig class, as shown in code below. I also need to use org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer as the servlet container in web.xml, for Jersey 2.x.

```
package rest.application.config;

import java.util.Set;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;
import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;

@ApplicationPath("resources")
public class ApplicationConfig extends Application {

    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        return getRestClasses();
    }

    //Auto-generated from RESTful web service wizard
    private Set<Class<?>> getRestClasses() {
        Set<Class<?>> resources = new java.util.HashSet<Class<?>>();        
        resources.add(Services.class);
        resources.add(CheckSessionFilter.class);
        return resources;    
    }
}
```